# How to handle stored UTC dates conversion in proper way in MySQL (with daylight saving)?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I saved user created date as `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` in the database with datetime .
Example:    `CreatedDate datetime,`

i know bellow will return correct result.

```
select  convert_tz(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00',@@session.time_zone);
```

My doubt is old data is require to check it comes under daylight saving or not. after that do proper calculation it is my major doubt. is it require or not. Please explain me clearly?

Example:

```
select case when  ( month(utc_timestamp())<6 and month(CreatedDate)<6 ) or 
                   ( month(utc_timestamp())>6 and month(CreatedDate)>6))
                 then  convert_tz(CreatedDate ,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) 
             when  ( month(utc_timestamp())<6 and month(CreatedDate)>6 ) then 
                        convert_tz(CreatedDate,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) 
                     -- require to decrease the @@session.time_zone with 1 hour
             else convert_tz(CreatedDate,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) 
                     -- require to increase the @@session.time_zone with 1 hour
        end as CreatedDate 
from tbluser;
```

For reporting purpose i use `@@session.time_zone` otherwise i will give CreatedDate(without conversion) to the front end developer. But still i have doubt there also is it require to check daylight saving and convert for old data ?
The above query has mistake but i am asking for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

From the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html):

> ***timezone*** values can be given in several formats, none of which are case sensitive:
>
> - The value `'SYSTEM'` indicates that the time zone should be the same as
>     the system time zone.
> - The value can be given as a string indicating an offset from UTC, such
>     as `'+10:00'` or `'-6:00'`.
> - The value can be given as a named time zone, such as
>     `'Europe/Helsinki'`, `'US/Eastern'`, or `'MET'`. Named time zones can be
>     used only if the time zone information tables in the mysql database
>     have been created and populated.

If your `@@session.time_zone` is either in the first or third form, then DST is already taken into account.

In the second form, you only have a fixed offset from UTC, so you can't really assume any DST applies.  Even if you could, it certainly wouldn't follow the logic you have written.  Keep in mind that DST doesn't apply to the whole world, and for those that use it there are different starting and ending dates and times between countries.

Therefore, you should ***not*** write any custom DST adjustments.  Just let `convert_tz` do its job.